# Invalid token for fernet

Tags: python, cryptography

I am encountering an error related to InvalidToken in the Fernet library. The problem is that an error occurs when I try to use the key from the txt file. I stored the keys in a txt file. But when I use the key from the file and use it, it says that it is an invalid token. How can I fix it?

```
key = Fernet.generate_key()
f = Fernet(key)

def add_new_id_and_password():
    global number_of_passwords
    global passwords
    number_of_passwords += 1
    add_new_password_window.withdraw()
    website_window.deiconify()
    word = add_new_password_entry.get()
    token = f.encrypt(word.encode())
    with open("id.txt", "a+") as file:
        file.write(str(add_new_id_entry.get())+"\n")
    with open("keys.txt", "a+") as file:
        file.write(str(token)+"\n")
    with open("websites.txt", "a+") as file:
        file.write(str(add_new_website_entry.get())+"\n")
    website_window_passwords.insert(END, add_new_website_entry.get())
    website_window_passwords.pack()
    

def look_password_and_id():
    if website_window_passwords.curselection()[0] >= 0:
        website_window.withdraw()
        password_window.deiconify()
        with open("id.txt", "r+") as idFile:
            id = idFile.readlines()[int(website_window_passwords.curselection()[0])]
            print(id)
        with open("keys.txt", "r+") as passwordFile:
            password = passwordFile.readlines()[int(website_window_passwords.curselection()[0])]
            print(password)
        decoded_password = f.decrypt(bytes(password.encode())).decode('utf-8')
        label = Label(password_window, text = "ID: " + id + "\nPassword: " + decoded_password)
        label.pack()
    else:
        pass
```

The first function is storing the keys. The second function is for trying to use the keys. The purpose of this is to encrypt the txt file. Id.txt has the ids. keys.txt has all the keys. They all correspond. So when id 1 is in the first line of id.txt, the first line of keys.txt is the key of the id 1.

Comment: It would be a better question if you write information about error logs and an example of id.txt together.
In addition, a link related to the Fernet library you are actually using should also be attached.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please add information such as what error occurred, which kind of data you have in your files, and other relevant debugging details.